# Is NoSQL or SQLite database better for large number of records, GPS tracking Flutter App?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, nosql

I am in the infancy stages of building a Flutter app for GPS tracking.  I will be storing GPS tracks and waypoints.  The GPS tracks could be several hours long with breadcrumbs every second or two. This would mean I could have several tables with over 10,000 records.  I know that SQLite is better for larger databases, but I'm also concerned about device battery life.  I assume a structured DB will be more time consuming to write to and thus will require more power.

I am not concerned about reliability of individual records, but I am concerned about overall database reliability.  A few dropped records is fine, but I want the database to be able to recover from such an error.

In this case, which type of database would be preferable, NoSQL or SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Sqlite as it is better with large tables.

But save the records for say 2 minutes and then write it to SQLite as a batch operation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check `Sembast` NoSQL database (https://pub.dev/packages/sembast), it's a NoSQL database in flutter app.

You can check this link:
https://medium.com/@hrishikesh.deshmukh445/persist-data-with-sembast-nosql-database-in-flutter-2b6c5110170f

"The whole document based database resides in a single file and is loaded in memory when opened." as the above article said, the read speed will be fast and battery use should be low.